ACL Permissions Related
Can anyone explain what is the usecase of all these

CREATOR OWNER
BUILTIN\Users
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES
NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
BUILTIN\Administrators

I know there are multiple documentation , however i need to know the difference of including this to my folder and excluding it with real time example. Could any one explain me?
